# Google Apps Script Drive.file.insert question

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a simple Google Apps Script to select an Excel file, convert it to Google Sheets via Blob, and then copy some cells from that to another Google Sheet. It doesn't work. 3 Questions:

1. Does Drive.Files.insert return a file object? I get an error saying
   source.getSheetByName() is not a function right after setting source
   to a Drive.Files.insert. (See below)
2. Whenever I try to put breakpoints in this section of code, they never break there, even though the code runs. How do I use the debugger/breakpoints here?
3. How would I specify a different location for the created Google Sheet ?

Thanks!

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(e) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(e.bytes, e.mimeType, e.filename);
  var excelFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  var fileName = e.filename;
  var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
  var fileId = excelFile.getId();
  var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;
  var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: excelFile.getName(),
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id: folderId}],
  };

  var source = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = target.getSheetByName("Sheet10");

  Logger.log("The values are " + sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 1).getValues());
  Logger.log("The values are " + targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 1).getValues());
  var targetrange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, 3, 5); //sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var rangeValues = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1, 3,5).getValues(); //sourceSheet.getLastRow()-3, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);

}
```

Comment: `.insert` does return a `File`. But `getSheetByName()` doesn't exist on Class `File`. Does it?

Comment: You're right. Thanks, @TheMaster!

Comment: Get the file's id. Use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` to get a object of class `Spreadsheet` from class `File`

Comment: Hi there jkearns! I strongly recommend you to take the approach commented by @TheMaster. Please, write back sharing your findings.

Comment: That was it .. It was a File, not a Spreadsheet. Didn't get an answer for numbers 2 and 3, but that's ok. 

Comment: I am happy that the first point got solved. If you still need some help, please write back answering my doubts. When you said «*they never break there*», where did you exactly put the breakpoints? By the way, here you can learn more about Apps Script debugger. Also, when you wrote «*a different location for the created Google Sheet*», could you please specify where you want to save the Sheet?